# Clarification of a statement in Jacobson's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Jacobson (in Basic Algebra $1$) defines a *separable polynomial* to be one whose irreducible factors have distinct roots. Then he defines a *perfect field* to be a field $F$ such that every polynomial in $F[x]$ is separable, and proves that if $F$ is finite or of characteristic $0$, then it is perfect.

At the beginning of the section corresponding to this, he says:

> We shall show in this section that if $F$ is of characteristic $0$ or if $F$ is a finite field, then there is no loss in generality in assuming that all the roots are simple.

I don't understand what this is supposed to mean. What is the "generality" in which there is no loss with that assumption?

This section starts at page $229$. The quote is the first sentence on page $230$.

Comment: Wlog. a perfect field $F$ is one where every irreducible polynomial $g \in F[x]$ has no repeated roots. This is equivalent to that any finite extension of $F$  is contained in some Galois extension

Comment: @reuns I don't know any Galois theory (and at that point in the book, the author still hadn't talked about Galois stuff).

Comment: Did you read my 1st sentence ? $\mathbb{F}_2(t^2)$ is not perfect because $x^2-t^2 = (x+t)^2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2(t^2)$ (its root generates the degree $2$ extension $\mathbb{F}_2(t)/\mathbb{F}_2(t^2)$)

Comment: I read it but I didn't understand it - I thought it was connected to your second sentence. What exactly do you mean in your first sentence?

Comment: In a perfect field $F$, if a polynomial $g(x) \in F[x]$ has a double root then it is not irreducible...

Comment: Why is this true? @reuns

Comment: Because read it again, this is the definition of a perfect field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "without loss of generality" is in the context of describing fields as splitting fields of polynomials.  So what it means is that if $E$ is any field extension of $F$ that is the splitting field of some polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$, then there exists a polynomial $f_0(x)\in F[x]$ such that $E$ is also the splitting field of $f_0(x)$ and all the roots of $f_0(x)$ in $E$ are distinct.  (In fact, the discussion shows something stronger: the roots of this $f_0(x)$ are the same as the roots of $f(x)$, just with the repeats removed.)

Comment: But how does this relate to anything?

Comment: Jacobson's stated motivation (in the last sentence of page 229) is the final sentence of Theorem 4.4, which requires you to have an extension which is the splitting field of a polynomial with distinct roots in order to reach a certain conclusion.

Comment: In fact, the final part of Theorem 4.4 turns out to be crucial to Galois theory, which will be developed in Section 4.5.

Comment: I still don't quite see what is going on. I know this is too much, but if possible, can you please take a look at the first paragraph on page $230$, and explain a bit what the author has in mind in the first two sentences?

Comment: That's exactly what my answer explains...I'm not sure which part you don't understand.

Comment: Okay, now I think I can ask the right question: what is this observation useful at all?

Comment: That's what my first two comments above answer :).

Comment: Alright, now I see. I had to read page $236$ to see what is going on. But really, I should get myself some other textbook!